# No need to consider resource usage for typecasts in Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, casting

While use Kotlin, I have questions about type casting.

1. I think, Downcast (like Any as Int) use some resources (expensive) but Upcast (like Int as Any) don’t use resources (or really few). Is my thinking right?
2. Some people say that Kotlin/Java don’t need to care anymore about casting resources because JVM keep developing. Is this right?
3. I want to check myself these thinks are right or not. How I can make sample sources on IDE? (Check running time? or memory uses?)

Thank you for your interesting, and I'm waiting your advice.

Sincerely.

Comment: Upcasting is generally pointless.

Comment: And worrying about casting performance is concentrating on completely irrelevant things, at least if your concern is performance and not the internal workings of casting on the machine level.

Comment: @BoristheSpider@Kayaman

Thank you for your advice. I solved my curious :D!
(I had situations I get values specific type on Map and casting Any for use, So I had above questions.)